Can't make the redelivery work with delay
In my app using MassTransit and RabbitMq, I have the following config with the purpose to have the message retried 2 times and then redelivered after 30 secs:
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(busCfg =>
{
    busCfg.AddConsumers(assemblies: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

    busCfg.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((context, name, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
        cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(2));
    });

    busCfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

And a consumer throwing an exception:
public class MyMessageConsumerConsumer : IConsumer<MyMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyMessageConsumerConsumer> _logger;

    public MyMessageConsumerConsumer(ILogger<MyMessageConsumerConsumer> logger) => _logger = logger;

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Consumed by MyMessageConsumerConsumer!");

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

I send a message like this:
  var msg = new MyMessage() { MyProperty = "Test" };

  await _publishEndpoint.Publish(msg);

I would have expected for the redelivery to happen after 30 secs, but after the first 3 retries, the consumer is called again immediately and indefinitely!
What is wrong?

https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions#redelivery

@ChrisPatterson Thank you very much for reply, but can you please say what is the problem in my code? Why doesn't it also work in the way I am doing it? How is AddConfigureEndpointsCallback different than calling UseMessageRetry and  UseDelayedRedelivery ? Thanks!

First, your statements are in the wrong order. Secondly, it's preferable to configure them using the callback, vs. on the bus itself. On the receive endpoint is fine as well, but realize that anything configured on the bus is always configured on every receive endpoint as well.

What statements are in the wrong order? Calling UseMessageRetry before UseDelayedRedelivery? The reason I am asking is I am following a course and this is what the author showed. Maybe MassTransit changed since then and he is correct.

No, the course is wrong. What's in the documentation is correct and has been that way since the beginning.

@ChrisPatterson I used the exact code from the link in the documentation you gave. The behavior is the same.  I edited my question with the exact code I am using. I also reset RabbitMQ to be sure it's in a clean state. I am using the latest release of MassTransit.

Does your RabbitMQ have the delayed plug-in installed? Probably not. The details are in the documentation.

I'm trying to learn MassTransit so my app does only what I posted in my question. I do nothing else. I will make a github repo but it's really the code I posted here, nothing more.

@ChrisPatterson Thank you, sir! I'm such a noob, I was indeed using the wrong image rabbitmq:3-management instead of masstransit/rabbitmq ! I should pay more attention to the documentation!
